# How to structure classes in a way that they can work together?

Tags: javascript

I keep not understanding some fundamentals about classes.

1. What factors influence whether we should make a few different classes or one big class? Is it just about preference?
2. How can I make class instances "communicate" with each other? (example below)

Here's a fake example illustrating a problem I keep facing and I'm never sure how to properly solve it:

```
class FlyingSaucer {
  constructor(){
    this.velocity = {x:0, y:0}
    this.isMoving = false
  }
  move(){
    if (inventory.load < 125){ //<-looking up Inventory class object
      this.velocity = {x: 1, y:0}
    } else {
      this.velocity = {x: 0.5, y:0}
    }
    this.isMoving = true
  }
  beamUp(victim){
    if(victim.species === 'cow') {
      inventory.cows += 1 //<-changing Inventory object
    }
    inventory.load += victim.weight//<-changing Inventory object
    cow.freakOut() //<-calling a method of Creature class object
  }
}
class Inventory{
  constructor(){
    this.cows = 5
    this.humans = 1
    this.load = 0
  }
}
class Creature{
  constructor(species, weight) {
    this.species = species
    this.weight = weight
    this.sounds = sounds
    this.isScared = false
  }
  freakOut(){
    this.isScared = true
  }
}

const saucer = new FlyingSaucer()
const inventory = new Inventory()
const cow = new Creature('cow', '25')
```

Now, I expect that I should somehow pass these objects to each other after creating them. But here I'm wondering what are my options?

Comment: Your flying saucer would need an Inventory instance for a start. perhaps `this.inventory=new Inventory;` ... then, instead of `inventory.cows` it'd be `this.inventory.cows` - and instead of `cow.freakOut()` it'd be `victim.freakOut()` - because it's the passed in Creature that will freakout, not always the `cow` instance

Comment: Read articles about [composition versus inheritance](https://www.google.com/search?q=composition+versus+inheritance). Favoring composition over inheritance will serve you well. I'd just add a property to flying saucer called `inventory` that is an Array. When it beams up cow or a human, I'd just [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) that into that array. Creating a class for everything is overly formal and can usually be avoided entirely in javascript. But, doing things the hard way is a good way to learn.

Comment: @Bravo Wow, no idea why it never occurred to me I can do that in a constructor. This already solves some issues. Is it possible to get the "parent" of a nested object? So if I put `this.inventory = new Inventory()` inside a `saucer` object can we tell `this.inventory` to do something with its parent object, the saucer?

Comment: of course ... have the constructor of Inventory take a "parent" object as an argument, and the inventory can then access its parent

Comment: When favoring composition, things "contain" other things instead of inheriting from them.